# Angular material tree and MatTreeFlatDataSource?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can a ready-made array obtained from a database be connected to the `mat-tree`? If my data is stored in  approximately in this form:

Time:

```
[
    {
       "id": "10",
       "duration": "22:30"
    }
]
```

Operations:

```
[
    {
       "id": "15",
       "name": "delete",
       "times_id": "10"
    }
]
```

Of official ([angular material tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview)) sources I can not find a suitable example.

Comment: You need to convert your data into tree form and assign it?

Comment: @Justcode Yes, is there any example?

Comment: check their documentation and do it on your own. if you stuck anywhere you can edit your question

Comment: you must have a json in the way {prop1:value,prop2:{prop2-1:value,prop2-2:value}...}

Answer (score 0):

Angular material examples on a [site](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) are built on top of material [examples](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/material-examples) scripts in their repo
For **MatTreeFlatDataSource** you can check [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/tree-flat-overview/tree-flat-overview-example.ts) file.